# Combobox with selected value and Autocomplete

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete, combobox, selectedvalue

Having 1 datagridview for products and 1 combobox for categories, I have set combobox selected value to CategoryID.

When I type in the combobox the first letters of the category name and press Enter the name is completed inside the combobox, but the relative field in the datagridview doesn't change  until I click outside the combo.

Please, is there a way to make pressing Enter key perform change in the datagridview, so that I can save modification directly on save button click.

Comment: how are you binding your categories to the combobox and updating the gridview? I did same thing today and it worked

Comment: @tcoder, I am using L2SQL through databindingsource and databindingNavigator to products (datagrid) and databindingsource to categories (combo) . All is working well, but could not use "Enter" key to update both at the same time, before persisting data to the database(save button of the bindingSourceNavigator).

Comment: I actually had a central method `fillGrid()` that is called from any point but I was not using bindingsource. In fillGrid I just had `mygridview.DataSource = MyClass.GetSomeData()`

Comment: Your method is more professional (less use of controls), many thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could update the categoryID in the Product bindingsource simultanuously at pressing "Enter" key on combo Autocomplete,  by using the next event : cboCategories_**SelectedValueChanged** as follows:

```
    private void cboCategories_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int val = Convert.ToInt32(cboCategories.SelectedValue);
    ModifGrid(val);
}
private void ModifGrid(int ModifiedValue)
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(productBindingSource.Count)>0)
    {
        ((Product)productBindingSource.Current).CategoryID = ModifiedValue;
    }
}
```

After clicking save button in the bindingsourceNavigator changes are persisted to the database.

Answer (score 1):

This way the gridview could be filled from any source by calling `FillGrid()`

```
    private void FilterComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string selText = FilterComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString();         
        FillGrid(selText);
    }

   private void FillGrid(string filterValue = "0")
   {
        //GetDefaultValues(if filtervalue = 0)
        //else GetValues(based On Selected category)
        //Bind Values to Grid
   }
```

Comment: in this case we do not filter datagrid rows by using combo, combo is only used to change category in the product table.